# How to pass data between tabs on Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have two tabs in viewpager. So in fragment1 I input a text and when in tab2 is selected and then fragment2 will get data from that text from fragment1.

ex: when I open tab1 -> I input a text is "abcd" -> I open tab2 -> I want to get a text is "abcd" from tab1(fragment1).

```C#
public class Fragment1 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        Singleton singleton = Singleton.GetInstance();;
        singleton.SetSource("abcd");

    }

}public class Singleton
    {
        private static Singleton singleton;

        string a = null;
        private Singleton()
        {

        }

        public static Singleton GetInstance()
        {
            if (singleton == null)
                singleton = new Singleton();
            return singleton;
        }
        public void SetSource(string text)
        {
            this.a = text;
        }

        public string showMessage()
        {
            return a;
        }


    }
```

```
public class Fragment2 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    public List<string> data = new List<string>();
    public void add(string t)
    {
        data.Add(t);
    }
    TextView txt;
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here


    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        //return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view2, container, false);
        txt = View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtgetdata);
        if (data != null)
        {
            txt.Text = data[0];
        }
        else
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "no", ToastLength.Long).Show();

    }
}
```

I have tried it but don't having the result.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of research/test & debugging and solved, try this out.

1. In your Activity

   - add public string tabFragment { get; set; }
2. In your source fragment

   - ie on click or that navigate to other fragment

> ```
> string tab = ((ActivityUser)Activity).tabFragmentAddUser;
> FragmentAddUser fragment = (FragmentAddUser); 
> Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tab);
> fragment.setValText("Hello");
> viewPager.SetCurrentItem(1, true);
> ```

3. In your destination fragment (ie which elements will be modified)

   - add a method like this

> public void setValText(string str) { txtUsrFirstName.Text = str; }

==================================================================

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.SetArguments(bundle);
```

in on create of the other fragment

```
Bundle bundle = this.GetArguments();
int myInt = bundle.GetInt(key, defaultValue);
```

optionaly two fragments should never communicate directly and should communicate through activity

From Developers website:

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) and [this](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/)

Comment: Don't having the result

Comment: Didn't get you can you elaborate?

Comment: `Bundle bundle = this.Arguments;
txtv.Text = bundle.GetString("key");`.
this.Arguments is null

Comment: you have to pass those when navigating otherwise it would be null refer the links

Comment: So we can't pass data without navigation
`public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Fragment2 frag = new Fragment2();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.PutString("key", "abcd");
   frag.Arguments = bundle;
   // Create your fragment here
  }`

Comment: You can - for eg: by setting data in a singleton

Comment: I want that . How to do that?

Comment: the application class is a singleton you can assign data there and get data from there for a starting point - or create your own singleton class

Comment: I got the problem at singleton